# Facebook Messenger Postback Called thrice

Tags: facebook, postback, bots, messenger

I have successfully created a facebook messenger bot. I have implemented messaging postback also in my app and it seems to work fine in my android device `(Messenger V 68.0.0.22.67)`.

But when I try with Samsung Galaxy S5 with messenger `V 76.0.0.13.70`, all the event `postback` are called thrice. I even tried with some other existing facebook bots to test the postback event in the same device and it is the same situation there also. I am getting response thrice for every postback.

Could it be some issue with the messenger version? I couldn't find any issue log related to this so far.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Facebook will retry sending the message if your bot doesn't return a response within a time frame. Have you tried responding with a 200 at the entry point of your application and then proceeding with your application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the signature sent back by Facebook in the headers does not match the signature you calculate for the payload. This returns a 500 to Facebook and Facebook retries this request twice (for a total of three requests).

**PROBLEM**

The problem is some of the characters have to UNICODE encoded.

For example:

> @ character has to be replaced with "\u0040" before the hash is calculated.

**SOLUTION**

I have simply done this in the **verifySignature** in Facebook Messenger module

`let hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1',this.APP_SECRET).update(JSON.stringify(req.body).replace(/@/g,"\\u0040").replace(/\//g, '\\/')).digest('hex');`

This article delves deeper into the solutions.

https://hackernoon.com/regenerating-a-raw-request-payload-an-impossible-task-e4133fb2571